# Cosa significa "gettare una diga" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Il caffè lo presi un giorno col Cavaliere, sotto, davanti alla piazza scottante. Il Cavaliere era il figlio del vecchio Cavaliere, che ai miei tempi era il padrone delle terre del Castello e di diversi mulini e aveva perfino **gettato una diga** nel Belbo quand’io ancora dovevo nascere.

Ho cercato alla voce "gettare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso che l'espressione "gettare una diga" (nel fiume Belbo) ha nel passo sopra citato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato di ***[gettare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gettare/)*** da Treccani che si adatta al contesto da te citato è il seguente:

> **1 c.**) g. le fondamenta, farle, murarle (anche fig.); g. un ponte, costruirlo
>   (anche di ponti provvisorî per il passaggio delle truppe);

cioè semplicemente costruire, il Cavaliere aveva persino costruito una diga nel Belbo.

Nell'ambito edilizio si usa spesso il termine gettare riferito a fondamenta e solette perché il cemento viene gettato nello scavo (o sopra i mattoni nel caso della soletta).

La *[gettata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gettata/)* è infatti:

> a. Colata di gesso, metallo fuso, calcestruzzo, e sim., nelle opere di
>   getto.